# Exportar datos de una lista de sharepoint a un archivo csv, mediante Azure LogicApp, usando la accion de "get Items"

Tags: azure, devops

El objetivo es obtener los datos de una lista de sharepoint(se trata de sharepoint on-premises, se encuentra en una maquina virtual), para almacenarlos en un archivo csv, esto mediante Azure Logic App, usando la accion de "get Items".

Lo que se hizo es instalar gateway en la VM, despues en Azure se creo un gateway, el cual hace que se vincule con la cuenta que se tiene en la VM,  se realizaron las configuraciones necesesarias  para el funcionamiento,  pero al momento de llegar a LogicApp, pide conexion con gateway, el cual se crea, agregando el usuario y contraseña, mismas que se usaron al momento de configurar los datos.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Entonces al  ejecutar el diagrama en LogicApp, aparece el error 401 "No autorizado", parece que es algun tema con las credenciales, en revisar la autorizacion y autenticacion, Alguna sugerencia,  que valores deben ir en los campos al momento de agregar con gateway.
A continuacion se presenta la captura en donde esta accion de get items
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]